# How to concat two strings in angularjs in controller

Tags: angularjs, string, url

I want to post some data using $http.

this is my url :

http://bananabook.net/api/rest/polls/create?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxx&oauth_consumer_secret=xxxxxxx&oauth_token="+$rootScope.user.oauth_token

i want to add this objects value at end of url :

```
 [{
    id : options_1,
    name : sdfsdf
    },
    {
     id : options_2,
    name :ddfgdfg
   },
   {
     id : options_3,
     name : erwwer
   }]
```

I want output url like this :
   http://bananabook.net/api/rest/polls/create?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxx&oauth_consumer_secret=xxxxxxx&oauth_token=xxxxx&options_1=sdfsdf&options_2=ddfgdfg&options_3=erwwer

I couldn't concat options to this initial url using this way

```
for(i=0;i<$rootScope.choices.length;i++){
     $rootScope.url.concat("http://bananabook.net/api/rest/polls/create?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxx&oauth_consumer_secret=xxxxxxxxx&oauth_token="+$rootScope.user.oauth_token+"&"+$rootScope.choices[i].id+"="+$rootScope.choices[i].name;
    }
```

Comment: for(i=0;i<$rootScope.choices.length;i++){
     $rootScope.url.concat("http://bananabook.net/api/rest/polls/create?oauth_consumer_key=xxxx&oauth_consumer_secret=xxxxxx&oauth_token="+$rootScope.user.oauth_token+"&"+$rootScope.choices[i].id+"="+$rootScope.choices[i].name;
    }

Comment: Are you really asking how to concatenate strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Something like this...

```
var path = 'http://bananabook.net/api/rest/polls/create?oauth_consumer_key=xxxxxxx&oauth_consumer_secret=xxxxxxx&oauth_token='+$rootScope.user.oauth_token;
angular.forEach($rootScope.choices, function(item)
{
    path = path + '&' + $item.id + '=' + $item.name;
})
```